# finding records which doesnt have a state

Tags: sql, sql-server

| AID | BID | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

I am trying to find AID records which doesnt have any 0 state in this example AID = 1 (will be multiple records)

Comment: please explain briefly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to find all the `AID` with no `0` state records you may use

```sql
SELECT
    AID
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    AID
HAVING
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN STATE=0 THEN 1 END
    )=0;
```

| AID |
| --- |
| 1 |

or if you would like to find all AID records where  the state is not `0` for any AID record you may use the following.

```sql
SELECT
     *
FROM
     mytable
WHERE AID NOT IN (
     SELECT AID FROM mytable WHERE STATE=0
)
```

| AID | BID | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: first one I was looking for thanks